# Java OPC-UA implementation to Android

Tags: java, android, opc

There is this pure java implementation: https://github.com/eclipse/milo of an UPC-UA Client/Server. Now I guess it shouldn't be too hard to implement this for an android application.

So my current progress is an empty android project, where I try to import the OPC Java-sdk. But since this isn't a JAR file, I can't import it properly...

Comment: According to this link you can try adding the client dependency https://github.com/eclipse/milo/blob/master/README.md from Maven Central.

Comment: Is this even possible for a gradle project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the artifact is only available from the Sonatype OSS snapshots repository because there are no releases yet.

fernandospr's answer is correct though, but you would need to either add the Sonatype OSS repository reference or clone the project and run `mvn install`.

Now for the unfortunate part: Milo is written in Java 8, so it's unlikely you're going to get it working on Android.

Comment: Is there another implementation of OPC-UA which works for android?

Comment: Not a free or open source one. FWIW, Milo may work on Android Nougat once it's released. Hopefully I'll be able to test get my hands on a phone that can run Nougat and test.

Comment: I always forget the foundation open-sourced that. Yes, you could build something on top of it. It's just a stack though, and not a stack + SDK, so you'd have a lot of working ahead of you just implementing all the application layer details of a client or server.

Comment: @TobiasW Yes the OPC Foundation stack works on Android - as do the commercial https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-java-sdk/ and the free https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-client-for-android/ (application) that are built on top of that. As Kevin mentions, though, working on the plain stack is demanding, but of course possible, if you want to limit yourself to OSS.

Comment: Did it get tested in Nougat yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using your maven dependency adding the following to your `build.gradle` file:

buildscript section:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
...
```

dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "your-dependency:version"
    ...
}
```

For more info, see the [Dependency Management Basics reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)